# (C# - Forms) How do i get user input from TextBox.Text?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to write a program that paints a polygon onto a PictureBox. I want the user to enter values such as the center's X and Y point, length, angle, number of edges to textboxes. Then I want to use the values in textboxes as parameters.

The problem is that the program throws different types of exceptions as soon as I launch it without letting me enter any values into the textboxes. I guess it takes the TextBox.Text as a null value or an empty string so other parts of my code fail.

How do I get TextBox.Text?

Also, if you have any suggestions about calculating the vertex points of a polygon please share it with me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ConsoleApp1;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int CenterX, CenterY, Length, Angle;
        public int Edges;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CenterX = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            CenterY = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            Length = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
            Angle = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
            Edges = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            int width = pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width;
            int height = pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height;
            int newWidth = width / 2;
            int newHeight = height / 2;
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform((float)newWidth, (float)newHeight);
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            Polygon polygon = new Polygon(CenterX, CenterY);
            polygon.LENGTH = Length;
            polygon.ROTATIONANGLE = Angle;
            polygon.NUMBER_OF_EDGES = Edges;
            polygon.calculateEdgeCoordinates();
            polygon.rotatePolygon();
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            PointF[] points = new PointF[polygon.rotatedPoints.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < polygon.rotatedPoints.Count; i++)
            {
                points[i] = polygon.rotatedPoints[i];
            }
            e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(pen, points);
            e.Dispose();
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();           
        }
        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    public class Polygon
    {
        Point2D center = new Point2D();
        public List<Point2D> edgePoints = new List<Point2D>();
        public List<PointF> rotatedPoints = new List<PointF>();
        private double radius, angle, length, rotationAngle; private int numberOfEdges;
        public double RADIUS { get => radius; set => radius = value; }
        public double LENGTH { get => length; set => length = value; }
        public double ROTATIONANGLE { get => rotationAngle; set => rotationAngle = value; }
        public int NUMBER_OF_EDGES { get => numberOfEdges; set => numberOfEdges = value; }

        public Polygon()
        {
            Point2D polarCoords = center.calculatePolarCoordinates();
            polarCoords.X = length;
            angle = polarCoords.Y;
        }
        public Polygon(double x, double y)
        {
            center.X = x;
            center.Y = y;
            Point2D polarCoords = center.calculatePolarCoordinates();
            polarCoords.X = length;
            angle = polarCoords.Y;
        }

        public void calculateEdgeCoordinates()
        {
            double interiorAngle = 360 / numberOfEdges;       
            for (int i=0; i < numberOfEdges; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    Point2D point = new Point2D(length, angle);
                    edgePoints.Add(point);
                }
                else
                {
                    Point2D point = new Point2D(length, angle+interiorAngle);
                    edgePoints.Add(point);
                }                
            }
        }

        public void rotatePolygon()
        {
            for (int i=0; i < edgePoints.Count;  i++)
            {
                edgePoints[i].Y += rotationAngle;
                edgePoints[i].calculateCartesianCoordinates();

                PointF point = new PointF((float)(edgePoints[i].X), (float)(edgePoints[i].Y));
                rotatedPoints.Add(point);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you enter into the text boxes? Which exception does occur?

Comment: Problem is that I can't enter anything into the textboxes. Program throws an exception before I can even see the window open up. 
I get System.DivideByZeroException at line 111.

If I move this code block inside Form's Constructor: 
```
CenterX = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
CenterY = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
Length = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
Angle = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
Edges = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
```
it throws an System.FormatException error.

Comment: _pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();_ and _e.Dispose();_ These are always nonsense. - Other than that: You must always check before you use any input. I see no suspicious division though.. Do use the __debugger__ to inspect all values when the exception is thrown!

Comment: Probably here, right `360 / numberOfEdges`? numberOfEdges might be 0.

Comment: Yeah I think that's the problem. It assigns 0 to `numberOfEdges` without actually taking any input. It's supposed to assign TextBox4.Text to it. But it doesn't because the program just stops working before I can enter anything.

Comment: Then skip the painting if your data is not yet ready.

Comment: You should take note that if you wire-up (subscribe) to the picture boxes `Paint` event, then it will get fired at least once when the form `Loads`. So, technically the picture boxes `Paint` event would be fired at least one time BEFORE the user had actually typed anything into the text boxes.

Comment: Granted, you state that you have set some valid default values for the text boxes in the designer and this may well be true, however… in the forms `Load` event the code NEVER sets those variables… `CenterX`, `CenterY`, `Length`, `Angle` and `Edges` are NEVER Set in the forms `Load` event. If the user clicks the button, then those variables get set, but since the event is fired when loaded, those variables are not getting set. I suggest you copy the code that grabs the values from the text boxes into the forms `Load` event.

Comment: I did what you suggested but it throws "System.FormatException".

Comment: Can you show the added code in the forms `Load` method? And what is the exact error and the line of code that throws the error… if shown. And does this error happen BEFORE the form is loaded and causes the code to crash and never display the form? If it does… then for troubleshooting… comment out ALL the code in the picture boxes `Paint` event… then run the code… if the error remains, then the problem is NOT in the `Paint` event. I am betting it will display the form as expected and this will point the problem to the `Paint` event code.

Comment: Also can you show what the initial values are in the text boxes?

Answer (score 0):

This is necessary to start off with

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out CenterX))
                CenterX = 0;
            if (!int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out CenterY))
                CenterY = 0;
            if (!int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out Length))
                Length = 0;
            if (!int.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out Angle))
                Angle = 0;
            if (!int.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out Edges))
                Edges = 0;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
```

Then also use this: (here's your 0 division if numberOfEdges = 0)

```
 double interiorAngle = 360;

            if (numberOfEdges != 0)
                interiorAngle = 360 / numberOfEdges;
```